# Random password generator test driver won't execute

Tags: java, passwords

I wrote code in the class Password that generates a password given a certain length. The test driver PasswordTest input different lengths into the generatePassword method. Both programs compile but when I try to run PasswordTest.java I get the error: exception in the thread "main". How do I correct this error and get my test driver working?

Here is the Password class:

```
    /**
*   Password.java -- Generates random passwords
*   @author Sam Harrison
*   @version 21-Sept-2014
*
*/
import java.util.Random;
public class Password
{
    public char randomChar(int length)
    {
        final int NUM_CHARS = 62; 

        Random rand = new Random();
        int num = rand.nextInt(NUM_CHARS);

        if (num <= 9)
           num += 48;
        else if (num <= 35)
           num += 55;
        else
           num += 61;

        return (char) num;
    }
    public String generatePassword(int length)
    {   
        String str1 = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890";

        Password randObj = new Password();
        str1 = randObj.generatePassword(length);
        return str1;

    }
}
```

Here is the test driver:

```
    /**
*   PasswordTest.java
*   @author Sam Harrison
*   @version 21-Sept-2014
*
*/

public class PasswordTest
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        int length = 3;

        Password randObj = new Password();
        randObj.generatePassword(length);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In no place are you actually generating a password. You need to replace the body of `generatePassword` with some sort of loop that accumulates characters. Right now, all it does is allocate a new instance of `Password` and recurse into that instance, which does the same thing, ad infinitum until you exhaust the stack or heap.

Comment: I'm lost on how to write the loop, I guess.

Comment: Well you already have `randomChar` (just remove that unused `length` argument). You can declare an empty string with `String password = "";`, and build it up by appending characters from `randomChar` with the `+=` operator. So all you have to do is declare an empty string, and append characters to it in a for-loop until it is the desired length.